# Get title attribute from <li> element in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have three "li" elements with unique title. I added aura:id="tabId" to "li" as well. In Lightning controller I'm getting all items using find function:

```
var tabs = component.find('tabId');
```

How can I get title attribute in controller for each "li"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sfdcfox figured out [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/200785/2513) attributes of HTML elements are accessible at `component.get("v.HTMLAttributes")`. This makes it possible to access the values in init methods, where `getElement()` would not work by design as [described here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/147140/2513).

So in your case, this would work

```
for (var li of component.find("tabId")) {
    var title = li.get("v.HTMLAttributes").title;
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that this [attribute is a documented API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_html.htm?search_text=HTMLAttributes).

Answer (score 1):

First thing to try is something like this:

```
var tabs = component.find('tabId');
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var tab = tabs[i];
    if (tab.isValid()) {
        var title = tab.getElement().title;
        ...
    }
}
```

See [DOM Access Containment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm) for some relevant background information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var els = component.find('tabId');

/* Will handle all case when you have one or more than one items. */
[].concat(els).forEach(function(el){
    var title = el.get('v.title');
    /* You have access to title here. */
    console.log('title: ', title);
});
```