# How can I access HTML attributes in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, attribute

I stumbled over this a couple times now so I decided to do some research, but found no one alse complaining about missing access to html attributes. These are my findings and I hope to get some more insights from the SFSE community.

I know we can access attributes of custom components that are part of our namespace:

```
<c:test aura:id="custom" foo="bar" />

var foo = cmp.find("custom").get("v.foo");
```

But the same seems not to work for html attributes:

```
<a aura:id="link" href="foo.bar">bar</a>

var link = cmp.find("link");

console.log(link);
console.log(link.toString());
console.log(link.getElement());
console.log(link.get("v.href"));
```

Results in:

[image]

It is a `SecureComponent` (not a `SecureComponentRef` like components from foreign namespaces), so why do I not have access to it's attributes? Why can't I even access its element? According to this [DOM Access documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm) I should have this kind of access! It didn't work in my `aura:application`, nor in my `aura:component` called by an action.

Switching on the Debug Mode for Lightning components it tells me:

> Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'href' of component
>   'markup://aura:html {5:0} {a-element}' is not visible to
>   'markup://c:my {1:0}'.
>
> Failing descriptor: {c:my}

---

There is one exception, where I was able to get the element and it's attributes. I had to let it throw an event and get the element out of the events context with pure javascript, but this is mostly not an option.

```
<a href="#" onclick="{!c.handleEvent}">trigger event</a>

handleEvent: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    var url = evt.target.href;
},
```

### Edit

Turned out `link.getElement().href` would work if it is **not called** `onInit` (as I did it) since elements are only available after rendering [as defined here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/147140/2513). So the the answer below is perfect since it works on init too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually because your link is converted to an [aura:html](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:html/specification). You could get the href like this:

```
    var link = component.find("link");
    console.log(link.get("v.HTMLAttributes").href);
```

Comment: smart, thank you! Any Idea why `getElement()` is null?

Comment: @Basti https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147140 ...?

Comment: solved it, and clarifies why `cmp.find("link").getElement().href` dind't work under these circumstances. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox where did you found this get("v.HTMLAttributes")' ?? Please share source

Comment: @user614946 It's in the aura:html documentation (I just updated the link).

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks :)