# Lightning container with external source

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iframe, lightning-container

I would like to have an `iframe` in a Lightning component.

I, first, tried to create a `lightning:container` as this:

```
  <aura:attribute name="url"    
                  type="String" 
                  default="https://www.google.com" 
  />

  <lightning:container src="{! v.url}" 
                       onerror="{! c.onError }" 
                       onmessage="{! c.onMessage }" />
```

but according to documentation:

> lightning:container allows you to use an app developed with a third-party framework, such as AngularJS or React, in a Lightning component. Upload the app as a static resource.

So I decided to use an iframe as this:

```
<iframe
  id="iframe"
  aura:id="iframe"
  style="{! v.style }"
  src="{! v.url}"
  width="{! v.width }"
  height="{! v.height }"
  scrolling="{! v.scrolling }"
  onerror="{! c.onError }"
  frameborder="{! v.frameBorder }"
  sandbox="{! v.sandbox }"
/>
```

And setting up the `eventListener` on message during Lightning Component initialisation :

```
  function(component, event, helper) {
    const iframe = component.find('iframe');
    console.log(iframe);

    iframe.addEventHandler('message', (event) => {
      console.log('received message');
      console.log(event);
    }, false); // It works

    const frame = document.getElementById('iframe');
    console.log(frame); // null
    /*
    frame.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      console.log('received message');
      console.log(event);
    }, false)

    frame.postMessage({ test: 'test' }, '*');
    */
    console.groupEnd();
  }
```

**This works** (receiving message) but I can not do `component.find('iframe').postMessage()`. Instead I tried to perform a `querySelector` on **id** but I am not able to get the HTML Element to perform a post message.

Do you have any workaround to do so ? (Version 41.0).

[Lightning Container Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/container_js.htm)

Answer (score 2):

HTML elements are rendered as [aura:html](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_html.htm) components, so you need to get elelment first:

```
var iframe = component.find('iframe').getElement();
```

should return the html element, but be aware, that it will only be available after the component is rendered, as [described here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147140/lightning-aura-components-component-find-getelement-never-accessible).

In case you are using a `init` handler I would suggest using `render` instead ([docu](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueRender.htm)):

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doStuff}"/>
```

So your action could call it like this:

```
iframe.getElement().postMessage({ test: 'test' }, '*');
```

Comment: getElement does not return anything I will then try in after rendering function.

Comment: @SimonPlacentino updated my answer with a render handler.

Comment: `iframe.getElement().postMessage({ test: 'test' }, '*');` in the render handler leads to an infinite loop.

Someone could confirm me that doing `component.find('iframe').addEventHandler('message')` and `component.find('iframe').getElement().addEventListener('message')` is equivalent because handled by Lightning ?

Comment: @SimonPlacentino Where does the loop come from? were you able to debug anything? The Handler/Listener thing seems to be another question.

Comment: forget about this.

What I did: 

onInit of component, dynamically create the iFrame with `$A.createComponent` and `addEventListener('message')` on my current `window` object (the only way for me to receive a message): and it works.

Thank you anw