# Lightning spinner doesn't show up in Promise setting

Tags: lightning-aura-components, asynchronous, ui, promises

In the `init()` function of my Lightning component

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <c:spinner aura:id="spinner" />
       ....
    </c:spinner>
</aura:component>
```

I am chaining multiple Apex callbacks by using the [Promise pattern described here](http://nebulaconsulting.co.uk/using-javascript-promises-to-chain-asynchronous-actions-in-salesforce-lightning/)

```
({
    init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        cmp.find("spinner").show();

        helper.asPromise(cmp, helper.doThisFirst)
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.asPromise(cmp, helper.doThisSecond)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.asPromise(cmp, helper.doThisThird)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                cmp.find("spinner").hide();
            }));
    }
});
```

But the spinner is never showing up although the callbacks need several seconds to come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be highly related to the following issue, if you are trying to select a html element in your `c:spinner`: [component.find().getElement never accessible](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147140/lightning-aura-components-component-find-getelement-never-accessible).

So as a solution you might get around this with using the `render` event to trigger your spinner. It's important to use a `thingsAreRendered` flag, since the renderer is called whenever you do any changes in your component.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.rendered}" />
    <aura:attribute name="thingsAreRendered" type="Boolean" default="false" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        cmp.find("spinner").show();

        helper.asPromise(cmp, helper.doThisFirst)
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                ....

                cmp.set("v.thingsAreRendered", true);
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                cmp.find("spinner").hide();
            }));
    },


    rendered: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        if( !cmp.get("v.thingsAreRendered") {
            cmp.find("spinner").show();
        }
    },
});
```